# Audio player/playlist for mix engineer portfolio?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to web stuff, but have some knowledge form school. I'm a mix engineer (google it if you don't know what it is), and I've made a website for my portfolio. Up until now, I've been using soundcloud and Spotifys API to showcase my mixes/songs. External javascript slows my site down A LOT, and I want to implement audio players instead - in order to get better speed and SEO.

My question is: What is the best way to code an audio playlist of high quality .wav files? I'd like it to look somewhat like the soundcloud API, as I like the design. You can check out how my website looks with those: https://www.sivertbjorneras.com

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy/paste code from already done HTML5 audio players with playlists:

- https://www.cincopa.com/media-platform/skins/responsive-html5-audio-player-with-playlist
- https://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-audio-player-with-playlist/

... and [many more](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=html5+audio+playlist+player&t=canonical&ia=web)

Comment: Thanks! I found "green-audio-player" and spent hours on hours to get it to work properly, but I did it!!. +1